# pjsip not working on android Lollipop

Tags: android, pjsip

I'm developing android app that uses Pjsip library I successfully integrated and worked on android 4.x android versions but it doesn't work on android 5 not even registering to the SIP, it keeps give me registration failed!

Answer (score 0):

Refer the following forum. pjsip has got issues with android version 5 mobiles

*https://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/issues/detail?id=2831*

Comment: I had successfully build pjsip for android and is working great above version 6.0, using ndkr20 (latest one). Why is it not working on 6.0 and below?
App crashes during loading the pjsua.so library with error as below,
cannot locate symbol "freeifaddrs" referenced by libpjsua2.so